# Saving the outcome in iPython (Python 3.6)

Tags: printf, ipython, python-3.6

Since I have to do long lasting computations with iPython (Python 3.6), I am looking for a way to save the outcome, so I can recover it once I turn on my laptop.

Do you know how to do this? I have looked it up online but I did not find anything.

Comment: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/storemagic.html

Comment: Thanks Alex Python! That was what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

From What I understand you are looking for a way that will help you save and reload kernel state and variables across boot.

You can do that using a module names as `Dill`
First do a pip install

`pip install dill`

Then in your notebook use for saving use

```
import dill
dill.dump_session('yourEnvName.db')
```

And to restore use

```
dill.load_session('yourEnvName.db')
```

There is also pickle and shelve but they both require additional steps so I have avoided them here.